# mysql select timeout for specific user

Tags: mysql

I have the following user who keeps running very complex analytics queries, that usually take 1m each query:

```
Id  User    Host            db  Command Time    State                 Info
97  tvs0XXX ec2...com:47703 ax  Query   55      Creating sort index   SELECT...
```

Is there a way to set a `SELECT` timeout for the `tvs0000` user above to 5 seconds? How would I do this?

Comment: @MarcB -- no, this is for a specific user only. The question you've linked to above is for a general query for any user.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html  "max_whatever" options. there's no option for time limit, just number of queries/connections.

Comment: @MarcB I see, so how would I do the grant to set execution time?

Comment: you can't. there is nothing in grant that allows a time limit.

Comment: @MarcB got it, thank you for the clarification. Also, I think this answer might be helpful for other people trying to accomplish the same, so I think re-opening the question and saying the above (I'll choose your answer) would be helpful.